# php code not working as expected form will not submit the correct data

Tags: php, html

so I've got this code that supposedly sends you an email after you entered a valid one and answered a security question. My problem is the fact that the form won't submit the answer i've given it. It always echoes "submit" on the begging of the second php block. Also if u can spot any other errors i might have missed let me know please. Thanks anticipated.

```
<?php
define ('DB_SERVER','fenrir');
define ('DB_USERNAME','ArchivrTW');
define ('DB_PASSWORD','vPOZOa1txS');
define ('DB_DATABASE','ArchivrTW');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$connection)
            {
                    die('Could not connect because: ' . mysql_error());
            }
?>
<?php
$test = $_POST['email'];
$query = "SELECT 'EMAIL' FROM 'USERS' WHERE 'EMAIL'=$test";
echo(strlen($query));
if(strlen($query) > 42)
    {
                            $query1 = "SELECT 'SecurityQ' from 'USERS' WHERE 'EMAIL' =$test";
                            $query2 = "SELECT 'SecurityA' from 'USERS' WHERE 'EMAIL' =$test";
                            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                            $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$query1);
                            $Results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                            $Results1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
                            $Results2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                            echo($Results1);
    }
?>
<form action="recover.php" method="post">
    <p>Security Question Answer: <input type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Type your answer here" /> </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="answer" id="answer" /> </p>
</form>
<?php
$answer=$_POST['answer'];
echo($answer);

                                    if (count($Results) >= 1 && strcmp($_POST['answer'],$Results2) == 0)
                                            {
                                                    $REQ_STATUS = 1;
                                                    $new_passwd = rand(1,1000000);
                                                    $to = $email;
                                                    $subject = "Archivr-Forgot Password";
                                                    $msg = "Use this generated password to log in then change it using the Edit Profile Menu";
                                                    mail($to, $subject, $msg);
                                            }
                                    else
                                            {
                                                    $message="Account not found or wrong security question answer";
                                            }

                                    if($REQ_STATUS == 1)
                                            {
                                                    $update_query="UPDATE USERS set PASSWORD =".$new_passwd." where EMAIL ='". $to ."'";
                                            }



?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first block works, problem is the form or the second block.

Comment: Your SQL queries look broken. Why aren't you selecting all three columns in one query? Why are you using `'STRINGS'` as identifiers, and not `IDENTIFIER` (without single quotes)? Why aren't you escaping data that gets put into an SQL string and makes you vulnerable to injection attacks?

Comment: First you should avoid using $test in a sql select without filtering for invalid input to avoid sql injection.  Second, wouldn't mysqli_fetch_assoc return an array?  So I don't know if the strcmp will work, and may give you an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com);
2. You have duplicate field names:

   ```
   <p>Security Question Answer: <input type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Type your answer here" /> </p>
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   <p><input type="submit" name="answer" id="answer" /> </p>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

Since the field names are the same, the submit button overwrites/replaces the text field, and you end up submitting a blank value.

Comment: Good catch the duplicate name attributes Marc. Lordie, I didn't even make it there yet lol I'd upvote, but I've no more votes left for today. Mind if I quote you in my answer?

Comment: I have no more mind today. I used up my monday quota of thinking juice by around 10am.

Comment: Mine's kind of went to mush too. That Espresso didn't do much effect for me earlier. Guess I'll ask for a double next time.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the incorrect [identifier qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for all your tables and columns being single quotes and not wrapping the `$test` variable in quotes; it's a string.

This one for example:

```
SELECT 'EMAIL' FROM 'USERS' WHERE 'EMAIL'=$test
```

should read as

```
SELECT `EMAIL` FROM `USERS` WHERE `EMAIL`='$test'
```

where you may have seen a tutorial somewhere, that the ticks resembled regular single quotes. They are not the same; *those are two different animals altogether*.

You will then need to follow the same method above and do the same for the rest of your queries.

Using this for example:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

would have signaled a syntax error.

Then this `mysql_error()` - That should read as `mysqli_error($connection)`. You cannot mix MySQL APIs. They do not intermix with each other.

---

You also don't seem to be doing anything with:

```
$update_query="UPDATE USERS set PASSWORD =".$new_passwd." where EMAIL ='". $to ."'";
```

Whether it's relevant to the question or not, you're not actually executing that query.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

Footnotes:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

- Plus, since you're using the entire code in one file, you will get warnings to the effect of "Undefined index xxx....", therefore you will need to use a conditional `isset()` and or `!empty()` around your executable code and for the POST arrays.

Passwords:

I'm hoping you're using a modern-day password hashing method, since this looks to me, being related to resetting passwords.

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Seems there are duplicate name attributes as spotted by Marc B. I didn't even make it that far, as I was busy "writing" all of this up. OP can use our answers.

Answer (score 0):

Both your form field and your submit button have a name of "answer". Rename your submit button name to "submit" or something else.